# Are all fonts allowed to use as image if we use CSS Image replacement instead @Font-face, Cufon and sIFR?

Tags: css, fonts, licensing, sifr, font-face

Are all fonts allowed to use as image if we use CSS Image replacement instead @Font-face, Cufon and sIFR?

**or**

When we use any font in any design we made, and add image in page using `<img>` or css `{ background-image:....}`, Is there no issue of font licensing in this condition.?

If we don't distribute the font in any mode SWF, eot, ttf, JavaScript just use for previewing and printing, Do we still need to check about licensing of the font.

Are we allowed to use Web-Safe fonts in print, fonts which come with OS?

How we can ensure about any font, the font is legally allowed to use to distribute and use in any form?

Comment: It would depend on the license I think...

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask a lawyer. This isn't even answerable with the details you've given. Some places, for example, do not allow copyright on fonts, only the programs that generate them (so a bitmap font is not copyrightable). Other places do. License agreements you agreed to to get the fonts may make other requirements, which may or may not be enforceable in your country.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the license for the specific font you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helpful link to Adobe's thoughts on fonts and their use on the web http://www.adobe.com/type/browser/info/embedding.html

Comment: Check the EULA (end user license agreement) of the company that created the font you want to use...